# How to set a watchpoint at a file in GDB to break whenever the file is modified?

Tags: c, gdb

While debugging my program I want to observe changes which the program is making to files and I want debugger to tell me when that happens

I am debugging a program which either creates or modifies certain files (let's say text files). A file can be modified from multiple places in the program and it can be modified a multiple number of times. The sequence of modification is important. I am looking for a way to set a watchpoint on the file just like we set on variables. Basically I want the program to break whenever the file is modified so that I can analyze the file content and observe the program further. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on a fprintf / write or whatever functions you use to write to files. Or implement a wrapper for these functions and add logging.

Comment: But that would break at all frprintf. It won't be file specific. I would expect that it break only for specific file I want to observe

Comment: Do you need to detect when the file is actually modified (with `write`, `ftruncate`, `WriteFile`, etc.), or whenever a library routine that buffers up data that may be written to the file somewhat later is called (`fprintf`, `fputs`, `fwrite`)? If the latter, and if you're using stdio functions, then putting a watchpoint on some element of the `FILE` structure, though non-portable,  may be the easiest way to do this. What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this easily. It's a novel concept, I've never heard of it at least.

Files are not typically things in the "scope" understood and managed by a debugger, so there's no way to tell a debugger to do this. Also, it's not quite how the single-step/debugging model works under the hood either, since files are a pretty high-level concept and breaking relies on stopping execution once it reaches a particular address.

You would need to put conditional breakpoints in all functions that do I/O to the file in question, and somehow come up with a condition to filter out only the file(s) you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches I can think of:

- Set a conditional break-point for your read/write functions that will break on your specified file descriptor / file pointer.
- Write wrappers for the read/write syscalls that logs activity for file descriptor and load it as a shared library using `LD_PRELOAD`.